# About the divergence of this series (harmonic series comparison)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have to say if the following series converges or diverges:

$$\sum_{k = 2}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\ln^2(k)}$$

Now, this is a special case of the Bertrand series, hence it's diverges.

The point is that I would like to arrive at the same conclusion **without** making use of the Bertrand series, and in particular only through comparison and minorisation via some other divergent series that doesn't involve logarithms.

If possible, harmonic series.

I thought about this:

$$\ln^2(k) \leq k \qquad \forall k \geq 2 \implies \frac{1}{\ln^2(k)} \geq \frac{1}{k}$$

Hence by comparison with the harmonic series, the original series diverge.

Is this ok or did I make some unjistified assumption?

Comment: Your answer is correct.

Comment: @Axel Thank you so much!

Comment: Of course the assertion $\ln^2 k \le k$ would need to be justified.

Comment: @GregMartin I would study the function $y(x) = \ln^2(x) - x$, proving it's decreasing in its domain, and proving that, at least for $x > 1$, we have $x > \ln^2(x)$. I mean I would prove it with calculus!